# Prevent expansion of `~`

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have a script which sync's a few files with a remote host. The commands that I want to issue are of the form

```
rsync -avz ~/.alias user@y:~/.alias
```

My script looks like this:

```
files=(~/.alias ~/.vimrc)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    rsync -avz "${file}" "user@server:${file}"
done
```

But the `~` always gets expanded and in fact I invoke the command

```
rsync -avz /home/user/.alias user@server:/home/user/.alias
```

instead of the one above. But the path to the home directory is not necessarily the same locally as it is on the server. I can use e.g. `sed` to replace this part, but it get's extremely tedious to do this for several servers with all different paths. Is there a way to use `~` without it getting expanded during the runtime of the script, but still `rsync` understands that the home directory is meant by `~`?

Comment: escape it, or quote your paths

Comment: That won't work, since it has to be expanded on the remote server.

Comment: It's expanded when you allocate the array. Just make a second array with the paths quoted in the array allocation and loop over indexes or something

Comment: Not sure if I understand. With `~` escaped, I get `rsync -avz /home/user/.alias user@server:\~/.alias` which does not work.

Comment: Why not `rsync -avz ~/.alias ~/.vimrc user@server:` ?

Comment: @pfnuesel What do you mean by `which does not work`? What happens?

Comment: The paths are not necessarily the same on the server. In the part of the scrip I left out, the path on the server might be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=(~/.alias ~/.vimrc)
```

The paths are already expanded at this point.  If you don't want that, escape them or quote them.

```
files=('~/.alias' \~/.vimrc)
```

Of course, then you can't use them, because you prevented the shell from expanding '~':

```
~/.alias: No such file or directory
```

You can expand the tilde later in the command using `eval` (always try to avoid `eval` though!) or a simple substitution:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    rsync -avz "${file/#\~/$HOME/}" "user@server:${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop, you can just do:

```
rsync -avz ~/.alias/* 'user@y:~/.alias/'
```

---

**EDIT:** You can do:

```
files=(.alias .vimrc)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    rsync -avz ~/"${file}" 'user@server:~/'"${file}"
done
```

Comment: This is a MWE. I have more than one file in my array.

Comment: `~/.alias/*` will pick all the files from `~/.alias/` directory

Comment: `.alias` is not a directory...; I changed the array in my question to make that more clear.